# How to use default ASP.NET MVC 3 validation with the standard Membership provider?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-membership

Every example I see of the cool new unobtrusive jquery validation in MVC 3 shows a custom class (usually Person). Adding the data annotations to that is simple, which really does show how cool the new validation support is.

But what about using it with the default membership system that's built into the default web template? Anyone "hack" in the unobtrusive validation yet? What would need to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default MVC3 Web Application template **does** use unobtrusive validation for the account screens, *assuming that you uncomment the script elements in the MasterPage* (or add them to the views directly).

For example, entering a password of less than six characters and tabbing to the password confirmation resulted in the following red text appearing next to the text box:

> 'Password' must be at least 6 characters long.

Entering a different password into the confirmation box resulted in:

> The password and confirmation password do not match.

This is because they have created specific "view models" for each of the views (if you take a look in the `\Models\` folder, you'll see `AccountModels.cs` with suitable models for each view) rather than the previous way of explicitly adding the fields to the method parameters.

The controller then passes the values from the models into the relevant methods on the membership provider.

Comment: Whoa, nice... I was migrating an MVC 2 site to 3... thanks for pointing that out.